# What resources should I consult before asking on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, research

**Motivation:**
Sometimes what I see in stackoverflow answers are quotes from official docs or what can be easily figured out using things like `man` or `help`. That was the motivation behind this problem.

Google, Q&A sites like stackoverflow, online forums etc. are of great help. But, sometimes they may not be necessary. Some simple solutions at fingertips may be available. Some methods may not be fast enough like googling but may worth it.

Some I know are:

1. Referring to official documentation/ text books (not fast sometimes)
2. Using simple tools like `man`,`--help` etc (faster than online help)

Are there any to add to this list?

Asked as suggested by [S. L. Barth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168333/s-l-barth).
Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: For the record, there is a precedent. Back when Anime.SE still allowed identification requests, they had a canonical Meta post on how to identify manga/anime.

Comment: @gnat Not quite a duplicate. The answer there is "do a lot of research!" The question here is "where do I start with my own research".

Comment: you could have deleted your post on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300162/228134 before reposting it here

Comment: Manuals, documentation, and a web search are essential to cover the obvious bases. After that, it's up to you. More research is always better, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you're using. Although I [did suggest a canonical per-site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300162/reducing-seeking-online-help-and-advantages-of-doing-so#comment975337_300162), computer programming is such a broad concept that it needs to be split.

For HTML and CSS issues, the official resource is the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/). It has the drawback of being very abstract.

For networking issues in the broadest sense, from HTTP to OAuth, the [RFC's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) are the official resource. More legible than the HTML spec on W3C, but still rather abstract.

For Java, [Oracle's Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are the first place to go, followed by the official API documentation.

For Android, you read the [official Android developer guides](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html). They assume you already know Java.

For .NET, there is the official .Net documentation.

For Haskell, there is [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Tag wikis on Stack Overflow also sometimes link to official (and unofficial) documentation. Take their advice with caution. We try to keep tag wikis clean and informative, but sometimes spam and self-promotion makes its way into a tag wiki.

That said, sometimes the best thing to do is simply to get a good book on the technology you're using. Unfortunately, it's up to you to find out if a book is good. We've tried book recommendations on Stack Overflow, but the Stack Exchange model does not lend itself very well to this.